# import pages from photoshop to indesign

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, page-layout

I am new to indesign. I always did all my print in Photoshop, which I know for multiple pages isn't the best route. What I want to do is start using inDesign but had one question:

Can I create all my page graphics in a .psd file separated out in folders to use with indesign?

For instance in one psd file I had 3 folders, each with different layers in them. Each folder had the page design for that page so when I am in inDesign all I do is add the text for each page and use the graphics from the psd folders. Thanks.

Comment: Typically when working with Indesign, you pretty much create every graphical element in Indesign or Illustrator and edit photos in Photoshop or Lightroom even. That is how you should probably do it in the future, but if you've already made it in photoshop, you should probably do as you were thinking. If I understood correctly, you want to essentially remove/hide text from your photoshop files and import the psd documents to indesign. Not the most ideal, but quite fine in this case. You'll still benefit from indesign page handling, if nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

When you start to work with a new tool, it's always worth taking the time to learn to use it as itself. It's tempting to try to bring the workflow you're familiar with from Photoshop into your expanded repertoire, but you'll end up fighting InDesign instead of working with it. In this case, however, InDesign has a feature that's designed for working with multiple layouts in a single PSD. You don't need to export anything or set up multiple PSDs unless you want to.

Instead, just make each of your page designs a Layer Comp. Show one layer group (what you're calling "folders") and hide the others, make that a Layer Comp and name it appropriately. (You want to be able to look at it a year from now and not have to scratch your head wondering which one is which.) Do the same for each of the other groups, so that you have a Layer Comp for each page background.

Place your PSD in your InDesign document and with it still selected, right-click and choose `Object Layer Options...`. In the dialog is a drop-down showing the currently active Layer Comp in the PSD. Change that to the one you need for that particular page in the document.

Although the feature was built with a different use case in mind (where the designer might want to give the Art Director or client multiple options for a single layout), it will work perfectly for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is something similar to 'Layer Comps To Files' under the File menu.

Here a [link](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/791896) to thread on saving Group Layers out as their own PSD.

This [one](https://forums.adobe.com/message/3689695) is about the same but for PDF and JPG. If you need more reference Google 'Photoshop export folders (or Layers) to files' should get you in the right direction.

Sorry, I can't help you more. I don't know a lot of JS or how to write custom batch actions with JS.

BUT as Joonas said, when you work in InDesign all the element on the page SHOULD be separate items. Take some time and learn InDesign; there are a lot of time saving tools -> [44 brilliant InDesign tutorials](http://www.creativebloq.com/graphic-design-tips/indesign-tutorials-1232639)